# Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuous, $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. Show that $f$ has a minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am not sure how to prove this. 
Although could a proof of even-degree polynomials with positive leading coefficient be helpful in this case?

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and such that $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. Show that $f$ has a minimum, i.e. that there exists $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ASEg.png)

Comment: Mean value theorem says that the secant line connecting two points will have the same slope as the tangent line of a point somewhere between those two points, if the function is continuous.

Comment: @Kaynex You need **more** than continuity for mean value theorem to be even formulated: you need differentiability. I do not see, though, how MVT would be the way to go here, even if its hypothesis held.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(0):= y_0$.
From the definition of $f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ for $ x \rightarrow +\infty$ you get that: $$\exists M_1: f(x) \ge y_0 \ \forall x \ge M_1$$
and the same for the fact that $f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ for $ x \rightarrow -\infty$:  $$\exists M_2: f(x) \ge y_0 \ \forall x \le M_2$$
You can suppose that $M_2 \le 0 \le M_1$ because, if not, you can pick a bigger $M_1$ and smaller $M_2$. Then $f$ has a minimum $m$ in $[M_2,M_1]$ because it's closed, and $ f(x) \ge f(m) \forall x \in [M_2,M_1] $. Since $0 \in [M_2,M_1]$ you have $y_0=f(0) \ge f(m)$ and, for how we chose $M_1$ and $M_2$, $ f(x)\ge y_0 \ge f(m) \forall x \notin [M_2,M_1] $. Then finally $ f(x) \ge f(m) \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ and m is minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Take any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$, then for some $a<x_0$ you get $f(x)>f(x_0)$ and for the same reason, as  $x\rightarrow +\infty$, then for some $b>x_0$ you get $f(x)>f(x_0)$. Since $f$ is continuous on the closed and bounded (i.e. compact) interval $[a,b]$, f attains it's minimum value, say $m$ for some $z_0\in [a,b]$. Then $f(x)\geq m$ for all $x$, since for $x<a$ we have $f(x)> f(x_0)\geq m$ (notice that $x_0\in [a,b]$, so $f(x_0)\geq m$), if $x>b$ then $f(x)> f(x_0)\geq m$ and finally, for $x\in [a,b]$ you have $f(x)\geq m$, of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ there exists $m>0$ such that $f(x)> a$ for some $a\in$ ran(f) for all $x\notin [-m,m]$. But $[-m,m]$ is a compact subset, $f$ is continuous so $f$ attains a minimum on $[-m,m]$

Can you do the rest from here?

Answer (score 1):

The extended function to $[-\infty, \infty]$ defined by $\widetilde{f}(\infty)=\widetilde{f}(-\infty)=\infty$ is clearly continuous by hypothesis. Being a continuous function in a compact set, $\widetilde{f}$ has a maximum and a minimum. Its minimum is clearly not attained in $\infty$ nor $-\infty$, hence it must be attained in $\mathbb{R}$, from which it will also be the minimum of $f$.